# Extract and set variables from input file c++

Tags: c++

So I want to get a specific part from every line of the input file.
So far I got this:

```
ifstream fin("text.txt");
string line;
while (getline(fin, line)) {
    if (line.find("Set") == 0)

    {

        istringstream sin1(line.substr(line.find("path1=") + 1)); 
        sin1 >> path1;
        istringstream sin2(line.substr(line.find("path2=") + 1)); 
        sin2 >> path2;

    }

}
```

From what I understood the `(line.substr(line.find("VAR_CAL_PATH2=") + 1))` part will take whatever it's after "path1=" and will put it into path1, I guess I got it wrong. My input file has two lines:

```
Set path1="somepath"
Set path2="someotherpath"
```

When the while loop ends I get path1="Set" and path2="someotherpath" but what I want is path1="somepath" and path2="someotherpath"

Comment: you are updating both the path1 and path2 for every line that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As @Jordfräs says, `find()` returns the position of the start of the string.
2. When you try to parse the `path2` value, you overwrite the value of `path1`.

The code with these fixes:

```
const string path1field = "path1=";
const string path2field = "path2=";

string path1 = "", path2 = "";

ifstream fin("text.txt");
string line;

while (getline(fin, line)) 
{
    if (line.find("Set") != string::npos)
    {
        size_t path1pos = line.find(path1field);
        size_t path2pos = line.find(path2field);

        if (path1pos != string::npos)
        {
            istringstream sin1(line.substr(path1pos + path1field.length()));
            sin1 >> path1;
        }

        if (path2pos != string::npos)
        {
            istringstream sin2(line.substr(path2pos + path2field.length()));
            sin2 >> path2;
        }
    }
}

cout << "path1: " << path1 << endl;
cout << "path2: " << path2 << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` function in `std::string` returns the position of the start of the string. Adding 1 will point to the start + 1, not the position after the string you search for.

There is plenty of good documentation of the standard library available, e.g., http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Answer (score 0):

Another (more general) solution for string variables could be:

```
ifstream fin("text.txt");
string line;

const vector<string> pathsNames={"path1=", "path2="};

vector<string> paths(pathsNames.size());

while (getline(fin, line)) {
    if (line.find("Set") == 0)

    {
        for(std::vector<string>::size_type x=0; x<pathsNames.size(); x++){
            if(line.find(pathsNames[x])!=string::npos){
                paths[x]=line.substr(line.find(pathsNames[x]) + pathsNames[x].length());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
//print results
for(std::vector<string>::size_type x=0; x<pathsNames.size(); x++){
    cout << pathsNames[x] << paths[x] << endl;
}
```